# Is it possible to configure an SSH client to use RSA/SHA1 signing?

Tags: ssh, openssh

I've upgraded my OpenSSH to 7.9, and now the hosts I usually connect to (configured at `~/.ssh/config`, but including even Github operations) are complaining about this (but still connecting):

```
agent key RSA SHA256:[hash] returned incorrect signature type
```

After some searches, I understand the server is using an outdated version of OpenSSH (7.4) that only signs keys with SHA1.
As I'm not able to update the server versions, is it possible to configure locally to always sign with SHA1, so I can skip that annoying message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This error message means something a little different than you think it does.  As you've noticed, an RSA SSH key can use one of three hash algorithms for signing: SHA-1 (the oldest format which is insecure), SHA-256, and SHA-512.  In this case, your client and the server agreed on using RSA with either SHA-256 or SHA-512.  This is good, because these options are robust and secure.

However, the SSH agent that you're using on your system is broken.  It was asked to provide a signature with either SHA-256 or SHA-512, and instead it returned with a signature using SHA-1.  This violates the protocol and is insecure.

So the problem here is that the program you're using as your SSH agent is either out of date or broken, and you should update it.  You haven't told us what program you're using for your agent or on what operating system you're running, so it's hard for us to say.  If you're not sure, you can run `echo $SSH_AUTH_SOCK` in a shell window, and sometimes the program name is in the path.

Alternately, you could create a different type of SSH key, such as an Ed25519 key, with a command like `ssh-keygen -t ed25519` and use that to connect instead.  This key type already uses a secure hash algorithm, so there's no need to worry about your agent providing the wrong type.  If your agent is reasonably recent, it should support this type of key natively.

Finally, you could use a different SSH agent: the one that comes with OpenSSH.  You can just run `eval $(ssh-agent -s)` to load it in a shell window.  You'll then need to add your key using `ssh-add`.

Comment: Hmmmm got it. Quite confusing, indeed! Thanks for the thorough explanation, sir.
So, I've updated "by hand" my old Ubuntu's SSH agent, so it might be possible that I left some piece out? It seems my openssl version is 1.1.0h, and `ssh -v 0.0.0.0` shows 7.9p1. What else should I check the version of? I didn't want to change my keys used as otherwise I would need to upload new stuff to the company's server(s).

Comment: If you're using the OpenSSH ssh-agent for OpenSSH 7.9, it should work.  So you should figure out what agent you are using and change it out.  Try looking at the `SSH_AUTH_SOCK` environment variable and see if you're using an old `gpg-agent` or `gnome-keyring` and if so, disable it from starting up, log out, and log back in.  Modern `gpg-agent` should be fine. though.